# Use Node.js as Shell

Tags: node.js, shell

How might I set up node.js as a shell replacement for bash? For example I should be able to run `vi('file')` to open a file and `cd('location')` to change between directories.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Since node doesn't implement anything a POSIX shell expects, this would almost certainly fail and possibly do horrible things to your user. Writing a compliant shell in node is possible, but too broad of a question for SO.

Comment: do u want to execute exe from node ? or something like shell commands on top of the Node.js API *shelljs*?

Comment: @aishwatsingh Shelljs isn't bad but really is just built on top of the nodejs api.  You can't use it as a real shell replacement to my knowledge.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to log in and have your shell be the Node REPL, and yet still be able to reasonably use your computer?

Comment: @Compynerd255 Yes.  For example I should be able to run `vi('file')` to open a file and `cd('location')` to change between directories.

Comment: In an attempt to keep this question semi up-to-date, a small Node POSIX project is available. [1] 3 years since question was asked. As noted, a real bash replacement will require Node POSIX support. Other steps still needed.   1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can! It will become much less straightforward to use your computer, though.

First off, you will need to know how to set this up. While you could likely set your user shell in Linux to `usr/bin/node`, this will leave you with only a Node.js REPL with no additional programs set up. What you're going to want to do is write a setup script that can do all of the below setup/convenience steps for you, essentially something that ends with [`repl.start()`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options) to produce a REPL after setting everything up. Of course, since UNIX shell settings can't specify arguments, you will need to write a small C program that executes your shell with those arguments (essentially, `exec("/usr/bin/node", "path/to/setup/script.js");`) and set that as your UNIX shell.

The main idea here is that any commands that you use beyond the very basics must be `require()`d into your shell - e.g. to do anything with your filesystem, execute

```
var fs = require("fs")
```

and do all of your filesystem calls from the `fs` object. This is analogous to adding things to your PATH. You can get basic shell commands by using [`shelljs`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) or similar, and to get at actual executable programs, use Node's built-in [`child_process.spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) for a foreground task or [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for a background task.

Since part of your requirement is that you want to call each of your programs like a function, you will need to produce these functions yourself, getting something like:

```
function ls(path) {
    child_process.spawnSync('/bin/ls', [path], { stdio: 'inherit' });
}
```

for everything you want to run. You can probably do this programmatically by iterating through all the entries in your PATH and use closures to generate execute functions for each, assigning them to the global object so that you don't have to enter any prefixes.

Again, it will become much less straightforward to use your computer, despite having these named functions. You will need to use `sh`/`bash`/`zsh` explicitly in order to run shell commands you find on the Internet, and programs that specifically call up your user shell and expect it to be Bash-compatible (or if you're on a system where `/bin/sh` links to your user shell somehow) will no longer work. But I can certainly see the appeal of being able to leverage JavaScript in your command-line environment.

---

**ADDENDUM:** For writing this setup script, the `REPLServer` object returned by `repl.start()` has a [`context`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_global_and_local_scope) object that is the same as the global object accessible to the REPL session it creates. When you write your setup script, you will need to assign everything to the `context` object:

```
const context = repl.start('> ').context;
context.ls = function ls(path) { /* . . . */ }
context.cd = function cd(path) { /* . . . */ }
```

Comment: For example I should be able to run vi('file') to open a file and cd('location') to change between directories.  Which I believe yours don't work like such.

Comment: And would it need to work automatically, right off the bat, for everything that is in your path?

Comment: it would be nice to create a superset Js language that allowed functions like `cd arg1 arg2` and `ls` as a function... I just realised I am describing CoffeeScript

Comment: @RayFoss thanks for the reference. Coffeescript actually looks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be an intersting proposition. Create a test account and tell it to use node as it's shell. See 'man useradd' for all options

```
$ useradd -s /usr/bin/node test
$ su - test
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works on mac and linux.

```
require('child_process').spawnSync('vi', ['file.txt'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bootstrap a repl session with your own commands, then run the script

```
#!/bin/bash
node  --experimental-repl-await -i -e "$(< scripts/noderc.js)"`
```

This allows for things like:

```
> ls()
> run('vi','file.txt')
> await myAsyncFunc()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something like this https://youtu.be/rcwcigtOwQ0 !

If so.... YES you can!

If you like I can share my code. But I need to fix some bugs first!

tell me if you like.

my .sh function:

```js
const hey = Object.create(null),
    sh = Object.create(null);;
  
hey.shell = Object.create(null);
hey.shell.run = require('child_process').exec;

sh.help = 'Execute an OS command';
sh.action = (...args) => {
    // repl_ is the replServer
    // the runningExternalProgram property is one way to know if I should 
    //       render the prompt and is not needed. I will create a better
    //        way to do this (action without if/decision)!
    repl_.runningExternalProgram = true;
    hey.shell.run(args.join(' '),
            (...args) => {
                ['error', 'log'].forEach((command, idx) => {
                    if (args[idx]) {
                        console[command](args[idx]);
                    }
                });
                repl_.runningExternalProgram = false;
            });
};
```

PS: to 'cd' into some directory you just need to change the process.cwd (current working directory)

PS2: to avoid need to write .sh for every OS program/command you can use Proxy on the global object.

Comment: Is there an easy way to remap characters and control characters?